# Do multiple heads allow multiple concentrations?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, concentration, spheres-of-power

The rules that describe what additional limbs can do fails to describe what multiple heads are able to do for you. My primary concern is, does having an additional head allow you to concentrate on more than one effect which requires a standard action in a round?

If it matters, the extra head in this case comes from the [alteration talent Additional Limbs from Spheres of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#TOC-Additional-Limbs).

Comment: I am really dubious about the relevance of Spheres of Power here; by including the tag, you potentially ward off answerers, where this *looks like* a question about the general Pathfinder rules, where Spheres of Power merely just happens to be the reason it came up. I’ve left it in just in case Spheres of Power added new rules for extra heads, but I’m not sure that adds anything to the question.

Comment: @KRyan I also think the tag can be removed, because even a summoner can get extra heads via the [aspect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/) feature. Since there is no extra rules in SoP for multi-limbs, it is not relevant, and the question could benefit from being broadened.

Comment: @Mindwin If Pathfinder itself had rules for this, I would have done so, but since it didn’t, it was incumbent on the Spheres of Power rules to provide them—which makes it relevant that the rules aren’t *there*, either (at least, so far as I could tell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no generic rules describing *any* benefit to having more than one head. Multi-headed creatures each have their own, specific benefits for having multiple heads, written into the creature description. These benefits don’t necessarily need to be the same, and certainly don’t apply to any creature other than the one that has them in their description. The most common sort of benefit seems to be [reduced penalties with two-weapon/multiweapon fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/ettin); I cannot find any such creature that gets multiple concentrations.

The rules really don’t allow us to read between the lines here and suggest any inherent benefit. Even something as simple as saying *vorpal* isn’t immediately fatal (since you have a second head) isn’t clear: it may very well that the loss of a head is fatal anyway (certainly, in a human, the blood loss from the severed arteries would be more than sufficient to result in rapid death even if there was another brain somewhere). So while multiple concentrations does kind of make sense, that’s a pretty big deal to add to every creature that happens to have multiple heads, with far reaching implications. Ask your GM if you like, but if it were me I’d be rather wary to allow it.

As for what the additional limbs alteration talent *actually does* when you give yourself another head, that would be up to the author to write out—and it appears to be missing. Putting it inside that bullet point would have been the best place for it, but I have done some searching to see if it was placed somewhere else and I have been unable to find it.

Comment: A creature with two heads do not bleed out from a vorpal wound unless it is also [wounding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/wounding/) ... The wonders of a game system.... I'd also not allow any kind of special bonus beyond what the feature that granted the extra head already allows. +1 – Mindwin 13 mins ago [edit: Typo]